# How to save value in database of array using ajax and php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am adding value using JavaScript dynamically. my code is following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var i = 1;
    function add_coll() {
        var city_value = document.getElementById("city_service").value;
        if(city_value != "city")
        {
        $('#colnew').append('<div id="businesshour'+i+'" class="row"><div class= "large-4 medium-4 columns">'+city_value+'</div><div class= "large-3 medium-3 columns end"><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="remove_coll('+i+');" ><img src="../img/cross_icon.png"></a></div></div>');
        i++;     
}  
     }
     function remove_coll(val) {
       $('#businesshour'+val).remove();
     }
    </script>
<select id="city_service" name="city_service">
             <option value="city">Choose One</option>
             <option value="Jaipur">Jaipur</option>
             <option value="Ajmer">Ajmer</option>
             <option value="Jodhpur">Jodhpur</option>
             </select> 
          </div>
          <div class= "large-3 medium-3 columns end">
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="add_coll();" class="button city-add">+ Add</a>         
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="colnew">
```

IN this code user select multiple value by clicking add button. when he select any value and enter add button this value display below select box. and user then also select new value like this.

Now how i can pass this value using ajax and save in mysql database.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is a little short on information. Can you share what you have tried, and what problems have you run into?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery Ajax POST example with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004233/jquery-ajax-post-example-with-php)

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Answer (score 0):

Store the city_value into array

```
var city_array = [];
```

and inside the `add_col()` method

```
city_array.push(city_value);
```

now you can send this array during ajax request.